# How to edit a .sx file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, microsoft-test-manager

I am trying to edit an .sx file associated with this addon for microsoft test manager: [Test Scribe](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e2c743ce-d9f1-4ed0-ab08-a4777bef06a4)

But if I make any change to the file in any editor test manager crashes. This should work since other people have said this is how they fixed the plugin not handling certain characters.

When I open the file in notepad++ it looks almost like an archive or something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, turns out it is using zip so you can open it and edit the files inside.